# Sprite brighter than texture

Tags: textures, graphics, unreal-4, unreal, materials

I have imported a new texture into UE, and have created a new sprite. I have setup the material of the sprite as follows:

[image: some material for pixel-art texture]

I have also set my texture as texture-parameter. But my sprite renders brighter than its texture:

[image: sprite brighter than texture]

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is probably the lighting in the scene - you can try to view your scene as Unlit (in editors viewport) then the texture should be the same colors as in the texture editor.

Answer (score 2):

Check the camera and light settings. The default camera uses eye adaptation to make everything in dark scene gradually brighter.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the sRGB checkbox and maybe change the compression settings.
You could also try changing the brightness and brightness curve values.

Comment: What should the compression/brightness settings be changed *to*?

Comment: I usually go for default or BC7. However, I doubt any compression setting will do alot of change. You will get the biggest change out of the sRGB and brightness settings. I suppose the reason why it looks different in your game are all the shaders that are applied (unreal also enables alot of shaders by default). Lighting plays a big role too of course.